# No video with supported format and MIME type found when trying to capture my screen and stream it in flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, mss

I'm trying to capture a video of my scream and stream it in a Flask server but it returns **"No video with supported format and MIME type found"
**
I have two files:

1- App.py -> for capturing the stream
2- Index.html -> to stream the video

Code:App.py

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import mss
import cv2
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import secrets
import numpy as np
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)  # For SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(app)

frame_queue = queue.Queue()
capture_interval = 0.1  # Adjust capture interval as needed
terminate_threads = False

def generate_frames():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 600}  # Adjust
        codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # QSV codec
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', codec, 25, (640, 480))
        
        while not terminate_threads:
            start_time = time.time()

            frame = sct.grab(monitor)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(np.frombuffer(frame.rgb, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480))  # Adjust resolution
            out.write(img)  # Write to output using QSV

            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80])  # Adjust quality
            frame_queue.put(buffer.tobytes())

            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            if elapsed_time < capture_interval:
                time.sleep(capture_interval - elapsed_time)

        out.release()  # Release video writer

def stream_frames():
    while not terminate_threads:
        frame = frame_queue.get()
        encoded_frame = base64.b64encode(frame).decode('utf-8')
        socketio.emit('frame', {'frame': encoded_frame})


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=generate_frames)
    stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=stream_frames)

    capture_thread.start()
    stream_thread.start()

    try:
        socketio.run(app, debug=True)
    finally:
        terminate_threads = True
        capture_thread.join()
        stream_thread.join()
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Real-Time Screen Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Real-Time Screen Stream</h1>
    <video id="video" width="800" height="600" controls></video>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        socket.on('frame', function(data) {
            var binaryFrame = atob(data.frame);
            var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryFrame.length);
            var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

            for (var i = 0; i < binaryFrame.length; i++) {
                uint8Array[i] = binaryFrame.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: 'video/mp4' });
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the codex and the encoding and decoding but I'm still stuck